# SQL query to count rows that contain value

Tags: sql, filter

I'm having some filter on the side of my website for example :

Filter set 1

- Alfa (?)
- Mercedes (?)
- Rover (?)
- BMW (?)
- Lancia (?)
- Fiat (?)
- Ford (?)

Filter set 2

- 2 seater (?)
- 3 seater (?)
- 4 seater (?)
- 5 seater (?)

Now I want behind the filter a number that returns how many results will pup-up if selecting that filter.

So there are for example 10 alfa's and 25 2 seaters in the database then behind alfa would stand "(10)" and behind 2 seater would stand "(25)". But if I select the Alfa filter it has to say "(4)" behind the 2 seater filter, because there are only 4 alfa's that also are 2 seaters.

I use this query to filter and return the cars, but this returns a complete array :

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE brand LIKE '%{$_GET[brand]}%' 
  AND seater LIKE '%{$_GET[seater]}%'
```

How can I alter it to return just a number?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to fill in the "?"s.  This would involve a separate query for each of the lists:

```
SELECT brand, count(*) as cnt
FROM cars 
GROUP BY brand; 


SELECT seater, count(*) as cnt
FROM cars 
GROUP BY seater;
```

Your query returns the combinations selected by the user -- each row or the count (if you used an aggregation query).  But I interpret the question as adding information to the lists themselves.

I should note that you can get the count for each value in the list:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM cars 
WHERE brand = 'Alfa'
```

However, I advise you to use the `GROUP BY` for performance reasons -- each query has its own overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(A_rowname) As count FROM cars WHERE brand LIKE '%{$_GET[brand]}%' 
AND seater LIKE '%{$_GET[seater]}%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `COUNT()` instead of `*` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cars
WHERE brand LIKE '%{$_GET[brand]}%' 
 AND seater LIKE '%{$_GET[seater]}%'
```